# How to change the argument of an onclick function dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, arguments

I’ve got this button here:

```
<button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
```

which gives me 1 cookie when I click on it.

```
function cookieClick(number){
  cookies = cookies + number;
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
}
```

This here is the function I use to get it to work.

Now here is my problem: When I want to increase the number of `cookie` I would get per click I can’t figure out how to do it. This is what I think is the closest to what it should be:

```
function upgrade(){
  if(cookies >= 100){
    document.getElementById("cookieClicker(1)").innerHTML * 2 = cookieClicker();
  }
}
```

But I’m guessing that isn’t quite right since it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<button id="cookie-clicker" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

```js
var numCookies = 0,
    cookiesPerClick = 1,
    clicker = document.getElementById("cookie-clicker"),
    cookies = document.getElementById("cookies");
clicker.addEventListener('click', cookieClick);
function cookieClick(){
    numCookies += cookiesPerClick;
    cookies.textContent = numCookies;
}
function upgrade(){
    cookiesPerClick *= 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works like a charm, Also thanks for the code I've learned quite a lot of new things just looking at it .